# Spontaneous symmetry breaking in relativistic QFT: (possible) equivalence of two definitions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Consider a QFT invariant under a Lie group $G$. Let this symmetry be implemented on the Hilbert space by unitary operators $U=$exp$(i \epsilon^A Q^A)$.
The fields $\phi_n(x)$ transform according to $$\phi_n(x) \longmapsto U\phi_n(x)U^{-1}=\phi_n(x)+\epsilon^A \delta^A\phi_n(x) + o(\epsilon),$$
which defines $\delta^A\phi_n(x)$. Furthermore I will denote with $|\Omega⟩$ a vacuum state of the theory.
I came across the following two definition:

1. **Definition 1.** *A symmetry associated with variations $\delta^A$ is spontaneously broken iff there exists an operator $O(\phi)$ for which*
   $$⟨\Omega|\delta^A O(\phi)(x)|\Omega⟩\neq 0$$
2. **Definition 2.** *A symmetry associated with a charge $Q^A$ is spontaneously broken iff*
   $$Q^A|\Omega⟩ \neq 0$$

While the second definition is physically very natural and seems the one preferred in most textbooks, when it comes to proving theorems regarding SSB (e.g. Goldstone's theorem), the same textbooks actually use the first definition.

Even though it can be shown quite easily that **1.** $\implies$ **2.**, the converse seems not so obvious to me, to the point I started wondering whether the equivalence actually holds.